# Wince - What does CreateProcess function do

Tags: windows-ce, createprocess, i2c

I know how to use CreateProcess function to run a process or exe. I have a strange issue that my program is being halted somehow during i2c communication. And when i run any test program using Telnet or using CreateProcess command, it start working again.

I am not sure what CreateProcess is actually doing here. Is there anyone have any knowledge on this?

Thanks,
Dnai

Answer (score 0):

`CreateProcess` simply launches a new executable it it's own process space in the OS, optionally sending in command line parameters.

It doesn't "do" anything else.  It has no effect on any system buses or drivers (like I2C).  If your app is halting, then it's probably a timing issue or driver bug.  It's certainly not the `CreateProcess` call.

Comment: I agree with you it is definitely not th eCreateProcess call. The thing i want to understand here is why CreateProcess is making system run again from halt state. Is it freeing some memeory i.e. stack, heap etc. or is it could be freeing mutex, semaphores. Or even it creates new thread so it may be causing some thread resets etc? I want to to know what it really does when it launches a new executable in its own process space. So that i can fix my halt issue similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new process may force a flush of the cache. If your driver is stuck because its accessing I2C via a cached pointer it may be that and operation that forces a flush will cause an actual read from the device on the next context switch and allow your process to continue running. But this is just a far fetched guess.

Comment: That is good suggestions actually. I would want to try that. Do you know how can i verify this? Is there any test code you want to refer.

Comment: You talked about I2C communication, so I would investigate the code inside the I2C driver/libraries involved.

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment. But i doubt if it is really a I2C issue. I just wanted to understand that what running an exe through createprocess actually doing which resets something and problem seems to be resolved. I mean is it resetting the cache, stack, threads, semphores, mutex or anything else. Thanks.

Comment: No resets on any synchronization object is automatically performed by createprocess. Obviously the process you start can do that, but the act of launching any process doesn't. Is your I2C stuff unblocked by starting any process? Then I would investigate cache issues.

Comment: Yes it I2C unblocked by starting any process as far as that process has some code in it (empty process doesn't work). But that code could be any like toggling any other gpio or running a loop to do print etc. If it is a cache issue then how to confirm it. THanks.